# ¿Cómo guardar una captura de pantalla en el server usando javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Me pasaron el sig codigo donde se """guardan " las imagenes
en el navegador pero ahora quiero guardarlas en el servidor usando php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function numerarImg () 
{
  // Selector Padre
var parent = document.querySelector('#editor');

// Cantidad de div
var divs = parent.querySelectorAll('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) 
        {
          divs[i].setAttribute("id","evidencia"+i);
          divs[i].setAttribute("onclick","agrandar(this)");
        }

}

function agrandar (inp) 
{

  let id = inp.id;
  let src = inp.src;

var modal = document.getElementById('imgs');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById(id);
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
modalImg.src = img.src;
$('#imgs').modal('show');

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar si lo que quieres hacer es lo mismo que subir una imagen?

Comment: la imagen ya la cargue con javascrip pero ahora quiero guardarla en el server php

Answer (score 0):

Intenta enviarla por [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) o ajax al servidor. Para esto tendrías que habilitar una dirección en donde recibas por medio de una petición POST la imagen y la guardes en tu base de datos o donde la quieras almacenar (tipo API). Por ejemplo:

**guardar-imagen.php**

```
<?php

$imagen = isset($_POST["imagen"]) ? $_POST["imagen"] : false;

if($imagen) {
    // Logica super genial para guardar la imagen en la base
    // de datos o en alguna carpeta del servidor
}
```

**main.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var form = $("form");
        var respuesta = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/guardar-imagen.php",
            data: new FormData(form)
        })
        .done(function() {
            // todo bien
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // ocurrio un error
        })
        .always(function() {
            // petición completa
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Ejemplo completo (ingles): https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Saludos!